# A two database setup give a PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "myTable" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I need to connect two databases in the same model, where in one I store data the other one to retrieve data.

I have a normal endpoint in my controller for the `create` action, that if valid, stores a new entry in my database and then executes a object method, that retrieves data from another and remote database.

in `MyClass.rb` I have the following method:

```
def get_data(param1, param2)

  query = "..." # My SQL query
  db_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter  => "postgresql",
    :host     => 'my_remote_host',
    :port     => 'port",
    :user     => "my_username",
    :password => "my_password",
    :database => "my_database",
    :timeout  => 10000
  )
  results = db_connection.connection.execute query
  db_connection.disconnect!
  return results
end
```

My problem is that, while the first `POST` request to the `create` action is successful, the following are returning 500 error. More specifically, `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "myTable" does not exist`

Is the `db_connection` replacing the existing database connection?

Comment: are the names of the tables different between the two databases?

Comment: yes, they are different tables with different names

Comment: Ok, that might be part of the problem. Its been a while, but I do recall encountering a strange issue like that, where the new connection effectively displaced the old one, so that subsequent queries were still using the new connection. But since there's no table named according to the usual rails convention (MyRailsModel -> my_rails_models) in your second db, it obviously fails.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of the fix, hopefully someone can shed some light. In the interim, if there's no other alternative, you could perhaps do something like `MyClass.establish_connection("original_database") before proceeding with additional queries on the original database.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found the issue. I was doing

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:my_db)
```

in my model, which was overriding the overall connection.  Instead it should be only

```
establish_connection(:my_db)
```